# multiple independent R sessions in Mac OS X

Tags: r, rstudio

I need to run multiple R sessions, and hope that they can be performed in different R sessions. In Windows, I am able to open an arbitrary number of R sessions, and run different codes in each session (both RGui and RStudio). However, in Mac OSX, neither R.app nor RStudio would allow me to open multiple independent sessions -- I have to wait until the first set of R codes are completed in order to run a second set of R codes.

Is there any solution in Mac OSX? This issues had bothered me long ago, so I'd like to hear your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: You can run multiple sessions on the command line, using Terminal or iterm, etc.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: thanks! I didn't thought about that... is it the only solution in Mac?

Comment: You can always just run R from the command line to get as many sessions as you want.  You can also install emacs and ess, which will also permit multiple sessions.

Comment: @alittleboy I don't know of other solutions. If I need multiple sessions I always use the command line via iTerm (a bit nicer than using the standard terminal app

Comment: You can duplicate the entire R.app package by option-dragging (and you can rename the copies). Haven't tried this with RStudio.app.

Comment: `open -n /Applications/RStudio.app` in Terminal

Comment: The easiest way to run multiple rstudio sessions is to use projects - I usually have 3 or 4 running at once.

Comment: @hadley on RStudio-server on ubuntu & try to switch between projects I'm always asked if I want to terminate my currently running session (say, when it's in the middle of executing some code). Does the code really keep running when you switch between RStudio projects on a Mac?

Comment: @cboettig switching closes the old one. I think there's some limitations with projects on rstudio server.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Thank you for all the suggestions. Here is a brief summary of the possible solutions:

1. Using Terminal: Run: `open -n /Applications/RStudio.app` in Terminal
2. Install Emacs and ESS which permit multiple sessions
3. Duplicate the entire R.app package by option-dragging (and you can rename the copies)
4. Run multiple rstudio sessions using projects

Comment: Small improvement to #1 (will use current working directory): `open -na Rstudio .`

Answer (score 19):

Opens another instance of an application in OSX:

```
open -n -a "APPLICATION NAME"
```

In this case you'd just do:

```
open -n -a "rstudio"
```

[CNET article source](http://www.cnet.com/news/how-to-open-multiple-instances-of-an-application-in-os-x/)

Answer (score 2):

I use this all the time on Mac OSX to open multiple Rgui sessions (similar to the Rstudio answer above):
open -n /Applications/R.app/
You can do this multiple times for as many R sessions as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for RStudio is to right click the RStudio icon of a current session and select "New RStudio Window":

[image]