# Conflict between singularity containers running RStudio Server

Tags: r, docker, slurm, rstudio-server, singularity-container

### Note

This may be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938305/run-multiple-instances-of-rstudio-in-a-web-browser). I'm evaluating. Will delete this if it is a duplicate.

I work on a slurm cluster. Using a script adapted from [here](https://rocker-project.org/use/singularity.html), I launch RStudio Server instances (community edition) in singularity containers and tunnel to them.

However, if I launch two at a time, even though they are completely different containers on different nodes, they seem to conflict with each other.

I don't know how to diagnose if this is an issue with singularity or RStudio Server and what that issue might be.

For example, when I log into a 2nd instance and open a project, it forceably tries to change the project the other instance is working in. If I try to switch back, one or the other instance usually crashes.

Perhaps the two instances are competing for the .RData file? Or, because I'm using the containers under my own PID, are the two containers fighting over everything I'm doing?

I know the community edition is not designed for multiple instances and isn't going to make this easy. But since I am essentially running them on completely different machines, in principle, there should be no problem.

Given that my best guesses are that the problem is either 1) the same user is running each instance or 2) They are using the same home directory, any suggestions for a workaround?